# Dynamically display Tables result into subform based on values of a combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have Form in a Microsoft access application

and in that form I have 2 combo box , one that display dates and one that display query names

Also , I have a subform that I would like to dynamically display tables , based on what the user select in the combo box

**Examples of what I'm trying to achieve :**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Select Case comboBoxQueries.value

Case comboBoxQueries.value = query1

MySubForm.SourceObject = Select * from Table_Employee where Table_Employee.date = ComboBoxDates.Values  


Case comboBoxQueries.value  = query2

 MySubForm.SourceObject = Select * from Table_School where Table_School .date = ComboBoxDates.Values  
               ...

End Select 


 End Sub
```

What would be the optimal way to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that would work because the field names will change in the record source, and then the sub form controls source won't match the record set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can use a table as a subform, but I do this kind of thing all the time using a subdatasheet based on a table. Try the following:

1. On the main form's **Load** event, clear the subform by setting MySubForm.SourceObject = ""
2. In the  **After_Update** event of the ComboQueries combobox, set MySubform.Sourceobject equal to the correct subdatasheet.
3. Set the .RecordSource of the subdatasheet to the sql string built from the combobox.

Here's roughly what it should look like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.MySubForm.SourceObject = ""
End Sub

Private Sub ComboQueries_AfterUpdate()

    Dim sql As String

    Me.MySubForm.SourceObject = Me.ComboQueries.Column(1)

    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & Me.ComboQueries.Column(0) & " WHERE Date = " & Me.Combo2.Value

    Me.MySubForm.Form.RowSource = sql


End Sub
```

Also, try not to use reserved keywords such as "DATE" as field names in your tables, it's a sure way to create unnecessary headaches later on.

Comment: I did not use the keywords date , I just used it as to illustrate my problem . Thank you

Comment: Glad to help. I did this quickly, from memory, so feel free to follow up with a comment if anything is unclear or doesn't work for you.